# Codeigniter Paginition does not show result on 2 page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using Codeigniter pagination class for the first.

Controller :-

```
public function index($issue_id = 0)
    {
        if(empty($issue_id))
        {
            $config = array(
               array(
                     'field'   => 'seltype',
                     'label'   => 'Type of issue',
                     'rules'   => 'trim'
                  ),
               array(
                     'field'   => 'txttitle',
                     'label'   => 'Title',
                     'rules'   => 'trim|required'
                  ),
            );
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);


            $this->load->library('pagination');

            $config['base_url'] = site_url()."/new_issues";
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->all_model->total_new_level_records(1);

            $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $config['per_page'] = 9; 

            $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

            $data['level_one'] = $this->all_model->new_level_issues(1,$config["per_page"], $config['uri_segment']);

            $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

            $this->load->view("new_issues_page", $data);
        }
}
```

I am getting total 33 rows from db and also I can see pagination in my view page which shows 1,2,3 Last. but when I click on 2 link it display no result.

EDIT :- The URL which I got when I click on 2 page is :- http://www.example.com/new_issues/2

Also I tries to print :- `$offset = $this->uri->segment(3);` but it does not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace like,it should be third segment of url

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

and your base_url should be like

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url()."/new_issues/index";
```

not other new functions

Comment: And I think you need to change for the offset also

Comment: I tried that also but it show nothing. Ok @Gautam can you tell suppose if I wrote $config['base_url'] = site_url()."/new_issues/page"; then I have to create page method in controller ? and if yes then what should i write in that code ?

Comment: then what code it should contain beacuse i wrote my pagination code in index fucntion

Comment: I know I sound stupid but really I am using pagination for the first time

Comment: then your $config['base_url'] = site_url."/new_issues/index";

Comment: and be careful with the site url,it may include index also

Comment: why am not anything in $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: I already told that you may need to change the offset url count to 3

Comment: I did that only I changed to $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);

Answer (score 0):

Just load model `$this->load->model('all_model')` before calling model function.

try

```
$this->load->model('all_model');

        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = site_url("controller/method");
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get_where('table name',array('where condition'))-> num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 9;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Comment: try `$config['uri_segment'] = 5;` and `$offset=0` as argument of index . . hope this will help . .

Comment: see edited answer and try `$offset=0` like `public function index($issue_id = 0,$offset=0)`